# Setting local date time for apps script triggers

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, datetime-format

The script timezone is set to Etc/GMT

I am accepting a date (using a datetime-local yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm) from user  to invoke a trigger function.

```
var at = moment(mydate); // say user sets mydate (local IST) as 2017-06-21T14:31 

ScriptApp.newTrigger('onClock').timeBased().at(new Date(at)).inTimezone(CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getTimeZone()).create();
```

this will invoke the trigger at 2017-06-21 20:01 local time IST

How do I make a code to invoke trigger at  2017-06-21T14:31  local time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inTimezone(timezone)` method only accepts valid "long format" JODA time zones.

[JODA.org](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)

You are already getting the default calendar time zone:

```
CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getTimeZone()
```

which returns the "long format" JODA type time zone, and that is what the `inTimezone()` method needs as it's parameter.

So, you don't need to get the `2017-06-21T14:31` information from the user, **UNLESS** their default calendar time zone is **NOT** the same as their local time.  If your situation, is that there is a difference between the default calendar time zone, and their local time on their computer; *and* you want to account for that difference, *then* you *do* need to get the local time zone.

If you really do need to get a time zone that is different from the default calendar time zone, then either the user needs to select a time zone, or you can try to get it some other way.

In your question, you stated that the time you got is: `2017-06-21T14:31`

That local time `2017-06-21T14:31` doesn't have time zone information in it.  If it had the offset, then you could use the offset to work back to the "long format" time zone.

You could have a drop down list for the user to choose from, with values that are valid "long format" JODA time zones.

```
<select>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+12">GMT +12</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+11">GMT +11</option>
</select>
```

If you really do need to get the users local time zone from client side code, see the following Stack Overflow answer:

[Stack Overflow answer - Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091399/2946873)

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset);
```

Then you will need to convert the offset to a value "long format" time zone.  You can do that by having a list "hard coded" into your code, and do a "look up" or construct a "Etc/GMT+##" time zone with code.  The offset is the opposite of the GMT number.  A standard offset of minus 12 is +12 GMT

## Offset --- Long Format

-12:00 --- Etc/GMT+12

Comment: First get the offset `var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset);`  Did you do that?

Comment: I do not understand.  What did you not get?